# how to formulate tsql query for Avg of multiple rows of a column based on corresponding to a value in a second column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a table I have 1 column( Total_marks) and another column(User_id), now i want to formulate a query for selecting the user_id and the avg marks(avg of the total_marks spanning over multiple rows)of each user id.

The table looks like:

```
    user_id  |  Student_id   | Total_marks

    U001     |      S0001    |    56
    U004     |      S0002    |    72
    U001     |      S0003    |    60
    U003     |      S0004    |    32
    U004     |      S0005    |    45
```

I tried :

```
    select User_id,sum(Total_marks)/ sum(nullif(NumberOFNOTNULL,0)) as avgmarks from [ABC_transctn] where sub_code='some_subject' and User_id!='' group by user_id
```

It gives the following error:

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'NumberOFNOTNULL'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'NumberOFNOTNULL'.

What would be the right query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate average then I guess this should do:

```
 select User_id,sum(convert(int,Total_marks))/ count(*) as avgmarks from [ABC_transctn]  
            where sub_code='some_subject' and User_id!='' group by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks Ranjana, but it still gives the error Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator

Comment: I did try that , as well as Cast but then it returns no result .just gives the column headings .. i have the data in place